# To limit the plot of a 'fit' function

Tags: function, gnuplot

As you see I am new to stackoverflow and Gnuplot, so please forgive me if I am not asking in the right way or right place ! :-

I have a scatter of (Y) data values/points collected over a range of dates. I can plot them against an x-axis of the dates and I have a 'fit' function of the form f(x)= a*x+b.

My problem is that this function extends/plots beyond the date range of the data points if I plot the data in a window which has a date range beyond that of the collected data. ie. the plotted function fills the whole window.

In other words : I want a window space (xrange) over say 50days but while the data is being collected (a few days only) I want the fitted function to occupy only the region of the so-far collected data and to then extend in sync with it as more data is plotted later.
Am I making sense ! 
[Showing the unwanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzEkL.jpg)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Add a separate range for the fit line:

```
 set xrange [10:50]  # applies to the entire plot
 plot 'data' using 1:2 with points title "Data", \
      [12:25] fit(x) with lines title "fit"
```

Comment: Perfect ! Very many thanks Ethan, I had played the xrange [10:50] bit but missed  the extra range for the fit bit   !